# i am trying to evaluate the confusion matrix and ROC curve in this code in NLTK.

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, roc, confusion-matrix

## This is code i am working on

Here is the code of short reviews of movies.

```
documents = []
all_words = []
allowed_words_types = ['J']
for p in short_pos.split('\n'):
    documents.append((p,"pos"))
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_words_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())
for p in short_neg.split('\n'):
    documents.append((p,"neg"))
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_words_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
words_features = list(all_words.keys())[:5000]
def find_features(document):
    words = word_tokenize(document)
    features = {}
    for w in words_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)
    return features
featuresets = [(find_features(rev),category) for (rev,category) in documents]
random.shuffle(featuresets)
print(len(featuresets))
training_set = featuresets[:100] 
testing_set = featuresets[100:]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

### Here i want to calculate the confusion  Mattrix and ROC

i just find the accuracy but i'm unable to find the roc and the confusion matrix, it will very helpfull anyone can help me out. thanks.

```
print(" Original Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent : ",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,testing_set))*100)
MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("MNB_classifier accuracy percent : ",(nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier,testing_set))*100)
voted_classifier = VoteClassifier(classifier,
                                  MNB_classifier)
def sentiment(text):
    feats = find_features(text)
    return voted_classifier.classify(feats),voted_classifier.confidence(feats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the confusion matrix using sklearn's metric package

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

More here
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Similarly, for ROC Curve

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html

Comment: Also, please go through sklearn and it's all relevant packages once and google things using relevant keywords. It'll be much faster and you'll have a better understanding.

Comment: I tried it but confusion_matrix() need two parameters as you mentioned, but in my code i do not have y_true and y_pred argument, can you tell how i can find those in my code. It will be very Helpful. Thanks

Comment: The `y_true` refers to the actual values/labels of your classes. I'm guessing in your case it'll be the category of the review. The `y_pred` means the value predicted by your model/classifier.